# Storing Domain Names in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

If I want to populate a DynamoDB table with a huge list of domain names, there are two parts to every domain name (example.com), the host name (example) and the top-level domain (com).

I am trying to determine how best to store this using a hash and range primary key. According to the documentation, you want to spread out the hash part of the key so I am thinking that should use the full domain name (example.com) and the range can be the updated date of the domain. This will allow me to query all domains updated after a specific date. Does this sound like a good design?

> To get the most out of DynamoDB throughput, create tables where the
>   hash key element has a large number of distinct values, and values are
>   requested fairly uniformly, as randomly as possible.

Comment: as always with NoSQL questions. It is best if you what are the queries you will be applying. read/write ratio, etc.

Comment: Write updates once per day and reads are sporadic and random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a domain name as Hash-Key and updated-date as Range Key would seem to give a good physical distribution of hash keys. However, if you have domain names being updated more than 500 times a second, I would evaluate alternate strategies like writing the udpates to a table with a UUID as a hash key, enabling a DynamoDB Stream on your update table and using that stream with KCL+Streams Adapter or Lambda to update a cache where you store the current state of your system. Finally, Query operations only pertain to one particular hash key at a time, but yes, if you use a datetime string as a Range key, you can definitely paginate forwards and backwards in time, starting with the most recent or least recent updates for a particular domain name.